# Personal Workbook macro is not running

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro and saved it to my Personal Workbook by following [Microsoft's instructions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566#OfficeVersion=Windows). Then, I added this macro to my Quick Access Toolbar. However, when I click it, nothing happens. The strange part is that if I assign the exact same code to a Button Click, everything runs well.

*Code is probably irrelevant now, but I just included it in case it may become relevant.*

**Here is the code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test(metric, greenNum, orangeNum, ws)
Dim metricName As Range                                                                             
Dim rowsCounter As Long                                                                             ' Rows loop counter
Dim numOfRows As Long                                                                               ' Number of rows
Dim numOfColumns As Long                                                                            ' Number of columns
Dim baseline As Double                                                                              ' Baseline to compute against
Dim newCellValue As Double                                                                          ' Each cell after baseline to make computations on
Dim columnsCounter As Long                                                                          ' Columns loop counter

Dim greenCell As Double
Dim orangeCell As Double

Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[^0-9.]"                                                    
Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ""
With regEx
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = strPattern
End With

numOfRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row                                                   
numOfColumns = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column                                  

For rowsCounter = 1 To numOfRows
    Set metricName = Range("A" & rowsCounter)                                                       

    If metricName.Value = metric Then

        For columnsCounter = 3 To numOfColumns

             If IsNumeric(ws.Cells(rowsCounter, 2)) Then                                            
                baseline = Math.Abs(ws.Cells(rowsCounter, 2))                                       
             Else
                If ws.Cells(rowsCounter, 2) <> "NA" And Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(rowsCounter, 2)) Then
                    baseline = Math.Abs(regEx.Replace(ws.Cells(rowsCounter, 2), strReplace))
                End If
             End If

             If IsNumeric(ws.Cells(rowsCounter, columnsCounter)) Then                                ' Check if cell value is number
                 newCellValue = Math.Abs(ws.Cells(rowsCounter, columnsCounter))                     
             Else
                 If ws.Cells(rowsCounter, columnsCounter) <> "NA" And Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(rowsCounter, columnsCounter)) Then
                     newCellValue = Math.Abs(regEx.Replace(ws.Cells(rowsCounter, columnsCounter), strReplace))
                 End If
             End If

             greenCell = baseline * greenNum
             orangeCell = baseline * orangeNum

             If newCellValue >= 0 And newCellValue < greenCell And Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(rowsCounter, columnsCounter)) Then
                 ws.Cells(rowsCounter, columnsCounter).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
             ElseIf newCellValue >= greenCell And newCellValue <= orangeCell Then
                 ws.Cells(rowsCounter, columnsCounter).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 165, 0)
             ElseIf IsEmpty(ws.Cells(rowsCounter, columnsCounter)) Then
                 ws.Cells(rowsCounter, columnsCounter).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
             Else
                 ws.Cells(rowsCounter, columnsCounter).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
             End If
        Next columnsCounter
    End If
Next rowsCounter
End Sub
```

**Then, I call this code in another sub:**

```
Public Sub runAll()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Const a = "test"
    Const b = 1.05
    Const c = 1.2
    Call test(a, b, c, ws)
Next ws
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

When I try to run this macro nothing happens - no errors, no output.

However, when I copy this code to a given Workbook's module and call `test()` on a button click - everything works perfect.

**How can I run macro saved in Personal Workbook without a button?**

Comment: When you run the code from the Personal Workbook, how does the code know which workbook to work with? “This Workbook” could be any that is open including the persobal workbook...

Comment: To answer your last question, you could [assign a shortcut key to macro](http://www.howtoexcelatexcel.com/vba/macro-mondays-how-to-assign-or-change-a-macro-shortcut-key/). As for why you can't get the Quick Access, perhaps you don't have the code saved in the correct module. It's hard to say without seeing what you have.

Comment: @SolarMike I thought it will automatically get the WorkBook that is currently open. But I think I see your point... You are saying what if 2 workbooks are open, correct? If so, do you know any solutions?

Comment: @ashleedawg I have macro saved in personal workbook

Comment: First you should use following code:  Dim MyBook as workbook    set MyBook=ActiveWorkbook     and use MyBook instead of thisworkbook.  Also your excel file which is the code is saved, should be open when you want to use your macro.

Comment: @tera_789 address the target workbook by name

Comment: @Hamed Thank you so much! It solved my issue. If you want, write it as an answer and I will accept it. It may also help future users.